# How add new library in existing cocoa-pod set in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I have added AFNetworking through cocoa-pod and it's working fine now i need to add one more library . so can i use the existing pod file or i should create new one 
please help me here how to do that.

Comment: Ofcourse your will use existing pod file. Just go to your project directory and open your podfile. add the library in podfile and again go on ternminal window and and init your pod

Comment: you can add pod 'Library Name' in your existing pod file.

Comment: can you show me your podfile ?

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

platform :ios, '8.4'

pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK', '~> 7.1.0'

Comment: you need to type 'pod install' to make actual changes (not update or init).

Answer (score 1):

You can add your pod like this. And after you done that you should run a pod install.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'myproject' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.14'
pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'
pod 'PureLayout', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Comment: pod install
-bash: pod: command not found added new libray but geeting like this

Comment: sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: if you're using el capitan: sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Use Existing Pod file -> Open -> Add the library name.

If you add your library then open Terminal window, set your project path, then install, its finally installed the Library.

Terminal window -> cd path -> pod install

hope its helpful

Comment: pod install
-bash: pod: command not found not able to install pod again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only need one pod file per project. I recommend that you look into the guides about using cocoapods on their website.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/index.html

I would recommend that you use the cocoapods OS X application as it will help you create pod files and update them.

https://cocoapods.org/app